# Responsive design: keeping proper offset for images that overlap

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

On a responsive website I'm working on, to display some products there are 2 images: 1 for the cover of the book, 1 for the chosen binding ("reliure" in french). See https://www.cemeq.qc.ca/fiche-produit/#/#Produit:81 or the following screenshot:  [image]

When in full size, the cover picture is 464px wide by 600px high and the binding picture is 484px by 610px. The cover picture should be aligned at the bottom right of the binding picture, so there is an offset of 20px horizontally and of 10px vertically.

When you check the link, you can see I almost got it, but in some resolutions there are glitches where the cover image is no longer correctly positionned relating to the binding image (you can see it clearly when the screen width goes over 2000px or below 700px) .

I'm out of ideas of what to try to fix this for all resolutions. Has anyone already done something similar or has ideas on how to do this? I would prefer a HTML/CSS only solution, but I'm not against using jQuery

Here is the code I have so far: 
HTML

```
<div class="column column-6 media-20-column-18 big-column margin-r-3p background-white padding-tb-7 text-c relative-height p-r" style="height: 812px;">
    <div class="p-r">       
        <img id="imgReliure" ng-hide="Product.isKit" src="https://dev.cemeq.qc.ca/assets/imgSpirale_2016.png">          
        <div class="container-imgCover">
            <img id="imgCover" src="https://dev.cemeq.qc.ca/covers/img1033_01_00_A_Cover.png">
        </div>          
    </div>                  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container-imgCover 
{
    width: 96%; 
    height: 98.4%;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
#imgReliure
{
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 999; 
    bottom:0; 
    right: 0;
}
.p-r {position:relative;}
.text-c {text-align:center;}
```

For the full CSS: https://www.cemeq.qc.ca/data/themes/cemeq/style.css?ver=4.5.1

Answer (score 0):

try to use the media querys to define the px to use in each screen size

[Here you can find an example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: So I would have to define a differen media query for every screen size between say 200px and 3000px?

Comment: You can only define the media querys in the range where you have problem, example, if you have to change the padding-left of a <div> only in the range 200px and 400px you will define @media screen and (max-width: 400px) and (min-width: 200px) and only in these size the padding-left will be modified in the other case will be the same...

Comment: Solved your problem Menard?